# Caesar 3 - Why don't I get any tax money from my senate?

Tags: caesar-3

I am on the second mission. My wages are 30 denari and the tax of 7% is way over 30 denari, but I still keep losing money. My senate has close to 30 employees and 100% of the population is paying tax. Is this a bug? Any help is appreciated.

I downloaded the game from Steam and I am playing it on Windows 10.

Comment: You should probably check your economic page.  And some more info about your city would be useful, as I don't think you've given us enough to go on.

Comment: @Frank Can you please let me know what additional information I should provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wages and how much the city spends are entirely two different things. You need to check the budget tab to see how much you spend.